# Simple sheaves, definition and characterization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi,

I have found the (unexplained) notion of a simple coherent sheaf $F$.
Is it right that one defines it as a coherent sheaf where every nonzero
homomorphism 
$F\rightarrow F$ 
is invertible?

And is this equivalent to: $F$ has no nontrivial (coherent?) subsheaves?

Thanks a lot and greetings!

Comment: To begin with this is mostly used for proper varieties. In nay case as a definition it seems OK (though I guess some people might make some restrictions on $F$ such as being torsion free). It is *definitely* not equivalent to having no non-trivial subsheaves. Consider for instance a proper geometrically integral scheme over a field and the structure sheaf, it is simple in this sense but there are lots of coherent ideals (unless the scheme is zero-dimensional).